# Disable Chrome Autocomplete/Dropdown Suggestions on WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, woocommerce-checkout-fields

I'm trying to disable Chromes Autofill/Dropdown suggestions for my customers when checking out. I have an address validation tool, but customers are still using Chromes drop down suggestions, and at times, street names and other detail is left out, so I'm having to contact customers manually for the information.

I've tried the following code for removing autocomplete for billing address, since text is the input type without success.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'change_autofill', 1, 1 );

function change_autofill( $field) {
    
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    
    if (strpos($agent, 'Firefox') !== false) {
        $field = str_replace('autocomplete="text"', 'autocomplete="off"', $field);
        return $field;
    }   
    else {
        $field = str_replace('autocomplete="text"', 'autocomplete="none"', $field);
        return $field;
    }      
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution below using the attributes provided here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

```
/* Disable autofill address */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'change_autofill', 1, 1 );

function change_autofill( $field) {
    
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    
    if (strpos($agent, 'Firefox') !== false) {
        $field = str_replace('autocomplete="address-line1"', 'autocomplete="off"', $field);
        return $field;
    }   
    else {
        $field = str_replace('autocomplete="address-line1"', 'autocomplete="none"', $field);
        return $field;
    }      
    
}
```